# how to add slide menu inside tabbar controller in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode5, menuitem, navigationbar, uitabcontroller

I have a requirement where i need to add a slide menu inside a tabbed content is it possible to  add a slide menu inside a UITabBarController and parent of this UITabBarController is a UINavigationController ?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your project it will be hard to provide a more in-depth explanation, but this should work:

Basically, I would recommend finding any one of the many open source "Swipe to Reveal" menus that are out there on places like Github.  With a quick google search [I found an example that might be useful to you](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/).

Really all you should need to do is set the whatever "Swipe to Reveal" class you use as the root to the selected tab that you are in  (If the initial viewController of the selected tab is a NavigationController then you probably want your slide menu to be the rootViewController of the NavigationController), and then you should be able to configure the menu to work within the selected tab just fine.

Please let me know if you need any additional help, and I can update my answer.  Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for you reply ..Well my scenario is like .first i have a login screen once the authentication is done i'm navigating to a tabbarcontroller,inside tabbarcontroller i need to place a slide menu one like in facebook but in left side     .. http://goo.gl/3VbX7R < mocup

Comment: Then it sounds like my initial response should help you resolve your problem.  Your VC stack should look like this:  UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> SwipeToRevealViewController.  Then you will have to configure the SwipeToRevealViewController to have a "content" viewController and a "menu" viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

I have done a similar thing for `UINavigationController`. And it is working for me.

I have created it as a re-usable component and added to GitHub, you can find it here: https://github.com/Midhun-MP/MMP_DrawerController

You can find a lot of controls [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Slide-out), better than my control ;)